# sscanf input not working

Tags: c++, scanf

I have tab seperated records like this

```
1000    Muhammad Aashir 0213-4211685    123456  0
```

first I have read the line by using fgets and now i am trying to extract contents by using sscanf, but there is an unexpected problem... please help I am beginner

here is the code

```c++
char buffer[SIZE];
Account req;
while(fgets(buffer,SIZE,fptr))
{
    cout<<endl<<buffer<<endl;
    sscanf(buffer,"%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%ld\n",&req.acc_num,req.name,req.mobileno,req.pass,&req.acc_bal);
    cout<<endl<<req.pass;
}
```

output of BUFFER is same as the record line

but after extracting values, when I am displaying the 'req.pass' the value is incorrect

req.pass is displaying '0213-4211685' but it has to display '123456'

Comment: `sscanf()` returns the number of item successfully read : testing this number is a way to decide if `sscanf()` succeded.

Comment: `"%d\t%[^\t]\t%s\t%s\t%ld\n"` instead of `"%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%ld\n"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY works like magic, by the way what it means [^\t] ? why you use it instead of %s

Comment: It means match anything except `\t` which is your separator character, you don't need all the other tabs and I would recommend limiting the lengths like this `"%d%*[\t]%99[^\t]%99s%99s%d"`, where it would be `99` if `req.name` is `char [100]`, i.e. the size of the array  `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sscanf will capture until reaching any kind of whitespace. In your case, req.name only contains `Muhammad`. This will cause the rest of your variables to contain the wrong info.

If you need to use `sscanf()`, you'll have to replace instances of " " in your name with an escape character, like "_" for example.